# rsync error when source is a mounted internal SSD

Tags: kubuntu, rsync

I am having an issue with my rscyn script where the issue may be related to the source being a mount point from fstab.  fstab mounts an internal SSD via UUID.

Here is a snipit from the code, and if the source is '/home/', there are no issues

```
SRC='/media/Movies'
DST='192.168.50.156:/srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-92b7ffea-567b-4480-aecc-5bb292e8a296/Backup2'

rsync -av --update --delete                  \
    --log-file='/home/jc/rsync-movies2.log'  \
    --exclude='*/tvshows'                    \

    $SRC \
    $DST \
```

I have also changed the ownership of the mount folder to the same as mine, however I still get the same error.

error =  rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1850) [Receiver=3.2.7]
/home/jc/backup.sh: line 67: /media/Movies: Is a directory

If I run the script with sudo, I will get an error with permissions.

Being that I am using -av, this should be fine for directories.

Are there know issues with using a mounted folder as a source with rsync or am I missing something here?

Best regards and thank you for your time,

Comment: You seem to have a blank line between the rsync command and the line "$SRC \\".  The error seems to be 2 errors concatenated. rsync complains that there is no src nor dest, whereas the shell complains after expanding a command "$SRC".

Comment: that blank line was it. My desk thanks you as I no longer hit my head on it :)